# How can I make an ellipse ease down to start in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm making a small interaction in p5.js where an ellipse moves when the mouse is pressed, then eases down to the start position when the mouse is released.

Code listed below:

```
var easing = 0.01;
var start =  290;
var x = 0;
var y = 190;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 200);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

if (mouseIsPressed) {
  
ellipse (mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
  } else {
    var targetX = mouseX;
    x += (mouseX - x) * easing;
    ellipse(start, y, 20, 20);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```js
var easing = 0.01;
var startX = 290;
var startY = 190;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 200);
  x = startX;
  y = startY;
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    x = mouseX;
    y = mouseY;
  } else {
    x += (startX - x) * easing;
    y += (startY - y) * easing;
  }
  
  ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the ellipse within the bounds of the canvas? Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Before drawing the ellipse check x and y to see if they are ourside the camera if so, set the value to the maximum it can go